# showing modular results of 2 combined JSON objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I am merging 2 separate json results into 1 object named `CustomerObject`.

Javascript code:

```
$scope.customerObject.push(result['customers']);
$scope.customerObject.push(result['servers_to_monitor']);
$scope.customerObject.push.apply(result['customers']);
$scope.customerObject.push.apply(result['servers_to_monitor']);
console.log($scope.customerObject);
```

the above code combines in the following object:

```
(2) [Array(6), {…}]
0:(6) ["customername one", "two", "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc"]
1:{customername one: Array(0), two: Array(2), etc: Array(0), etc: 
Array(0), etc: Array(3), …}
length:2
```

I am only iterating through the values of `customerObject[0]`
however there are values that need to be displayed from `<p class="mapsColor">{{customerObject[1]}} need to be iterated through as well</p>`

I could acces both values if I do an **ng-repeat** through the entire `customerObject` however that would mean it would only repeat twice (2 objects with objects inside of them) and I do need it to repeat for each customer in the list(stored in `customerObject[0]`).

`CustomerObject[1]` contains a number of objects filled with data. 
Current Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in customerObject[0]  " class="{{css}}" style="border-radius: 15px">
    <div  style="float: left; border-radius: 15px !important;" id="{{row}}" ng class="google_maps"></div>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 15px;">
    <div class="pull-right  mapsLegenda"   id="mapsRedBox"> 
        <h1 id="header_{{makeIdPickable(row)}}" class="pull-left  mapsTotal" style=" font-size: x-large !important; color: white ;">{{row}}: {{totals[$index]}}</h1>
        <br>
        <ul >
            <li >
                    <div class="mapsColor">
                <p class="mapsColor">{{customerObject[1].customername[0]['servername']}}</p>
                    <div class="color-box"  style="background-color: #{{server.icon_color}}; display: block; width: 10px; height: 10px"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
<div >
```

[image: currently]

With the above code I am displaying the customer name correctly with the {{row}}(black bars in the picture) however I can't display the values of `customerobject[1]` (currently the same for each one) accordingly which is what I need to do. So `test456` being replaced by the according value from `customerobject[1]`

Please do tell if I need to explain better and if my question is unclear or too broad.

Comment: can you create a sample JSON file and update in your answer. I cant get your question very well as of now

Comment: the results are result of an query of which the return values are jsonencoded, so no seperate json file in the project.

Comment: Do you need something like customerObject[1][row][0]['servername']? where row will be "customername one", "two", "etc", "etc", "etc", "etc" and it will access the properties inside  customerObject[1]

Comment: yes, something like that, currently {{row}} is already displaying the right customer name(can't show them because privacy) and the code is repeat once for each customer(so 6 times)  however i can't figure out a way to display the values from customerObject[1] that belong to their customer respectively

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to solve my own problem, apparently it is possible to use the {{row}} element from customerobject[0] as a parameter further on, the only downside from this implementation is that i need to add a line for each server. Since they will probably never become more than 4 in my case its not a huge issue. But something to consider should you face a similar problem yourself.

{{customerObject[1][row][0].servername}}

[image: this repeats for each in customers]

so for these 3 shown above you need 3 lines, 1 for each server.

```
                <p ng-show="customerObject[1][row][0].servername != ' '" class="mapsColor">{{customerObject[1][row][0].servername}}</p>
                <p ng-show="customerObject[1][row][1].servername != ' '" class="mapsColor">{{customerObject[1][row][1].servername}}</p>
                <p ng-show="customerObject[1][row][2].servername != ' '" class="mapsColor">{{customerObject[1][row][2].servername}}</p>
```

I know, ugly as hell but since i can come up with a better solution this will have to do sadly, should anyone know a better way, do tell :)